# How to proxy for a DEX router in ganache (development)?

Tags: contract-development, ganache, decentralized-exchange, router

I am testing a smart contract that uses a Pancake Swap as DEX exchange/router. For learning purposes, I am trying to setup everything in local environment. I have successfully setup ganache in the local environment. However, when I deploy the contract, it fails as the current DEX router address is for pancake-swap.

I was wondering if there is any way to proxy for a DEX router in local environment. Can I use Uniswap router for development environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. There is no proxy but to run pancake swap in testnet;
Here is a complete procedure to run it.
https://github.com/nhancv/pancake-swap-testnet#readme

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. It is better to include the main ideas in the answer and only use the link to fill the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use already deployed pancakeswap contracts by locally forking mainnet (using hardhat node/ganache-cli), using a BSC RPC server (via Moralis for instance, the officials from Binance being quite unreliable-this is a personal opinion).

See this for Truffle/ganache-cli : https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive

And this for Hardhat : https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html